# How can i remotely access the windows services of a remote host in workgroup computers?.Logon user returns with error code 1326

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services

I am writing an application which is used to manipulate the windows services. My computer is in a workgroup. But i couldn't get access to the machine. I've tried Impersonation using LogonUser(). But is not working. I am able to manipulate using Remote Desktop connection, however i couldn't access programatically.

```
        ImpersonateUser ImpersonatedUser = new ImpersonateUser();
        ImpersonatedUser.Impersonate(Domain, Username, password);
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("servicename", host_name);
        Console.WriteLine("Success."); 


//impersonation.
public class ImpersonateUser
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(
        String lpszUsername,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        private static IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
        private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;
        // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand that it
        // runs with FullTrust.
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string password)
        {
            //try
            {
                // Use the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
                // the specified user, domain, and password.
                const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
                // Passing this parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
                const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
                tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                // ---- Step - 1
                // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
                bool returnValue = LogonUser(
                userName,
                domainName,
                password,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                ref tokenHandle); // tokenHandle - new security token
                if (false == returnValue)
                {
                    int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
                }
                // ---- Step - 2
                WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
                // ---- Step - 3
                {
                    impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
                }
            }
        }
        // Stops impersonation
        public void Undo()
        {
            impersonatedUser.Undo();
            // Free the tokens.
            if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```